# How to get GKE cluster Hash value to update GCP firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

We are creating a GKE cluster using Terraform module and then deploying Istio on top of it using modules. But before deploying Istio we need to update the `gke-<cluster-name>-<cluster-hash>-master` firewall rule which is automatically created with the cluster, to open ports **15017** and **15021** to the target nodes. Is there a way to do it natively via terraform i.e. after creating the GKE cluster, the same terraform template should be able to update the firewall rules subsequently?

We are facing challenges to fetch and create strings locally for the below:

Master firewall rule name - `gke-cluster-b00977fd-master`

Target node tags - `gke-cluster-b00977fd-node`

If we are able to create these strings then we will be able to update or create a desired firewall rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to the first 8 characters of the cluster's ID.

I assume you can craft either of the following commands in the form of a Terraform script:

```bash
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT]"
LOCATION="[CLUSTER-LOCATION]"
CLUSTER="[CLUSTER-NAME]"
```

And:

```bash
HASH=$(\
  gcloud container clusters describe  ${NAME} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${LOCATION} \
--format="value(id)") && \
HASH=${HASH:0:8} && \
echo ${HASH}
```

Or:

```bash
NAME="projects/${PROJECT}/locations/${LOCATION}/clusters/${CLUSTER}"

HASH=$(\
  curl \
  --silent \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed \
  https://container.googleapis.com/v1/${NAME}  \
  | jq -r .id[:8]) && \
echo ${HASH}
```

> **NOTE** It's hacky and Google could revise this approach. I'm surprised that this isn't already solved by Istio deployments given that Google's a contributor and provides way to deploy Istio to GKE.

Comment: Hey, @Daz thank you for your suggestion it worked as expected and yes, it sounds hacky that's why now we would like to create a separate tag for all the nodes in the node pool via terraform and apply it in the separate firewall rule rather than updating the master rule which was auto-created with the GKE cluster. That way we can be future proof even if GCP revise its approach.

Comment: You're welcome! That sounds like a good solution to this problems